# manipulating strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list

im just in a beginner cmpt course for python and just learning about lists. One of our questions is to make a function that will recieve something like this(may have more than just 2 values)
['15--356', '9--24']
and create this
[15, 9, -1, 356, 24]
where -1 will always be the middle value.

I`m really lost on how to do this. A little guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
>>> lis = ['15--356', '9--24']
>>> new_lis = [int(z) for x in zip(*(y.split('--')for y in lis)) for z in x]
>>> new_lis
[15, 9, 356, 24]
>>> new_lis.insert(len(new_lis)/2, -1)
>>> new_lis
[15, 9, -1, 356, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

Making things extra-explicit:

```
step1 = [x.split('--') for x in input_list]
step2 = [int(elem) for sublist in step1 for elem in sublist] #or itertools.chain
halfway = len(step2) // 2 #python3 syntax
step2.insert(halfway,-1)
```